# Are there any CI purified Firefox forks?

Tags: software, forking, package, release

Are there any continuously integrated forks of Mozilla Firefox that only use the open source code?

If not, why?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are several continuously integrated forks of Mozilla Firefox that only use the open source code. Some examples include:

**Waterfox:** This fork is based on the Firefox codebase but is optimized for 64-bit systems. It also includes some additional privacy features not found in the main Firefox build.

**Pale Moon:** This fork is based on an older version of Firefox and is optimized for older systems and processors. It also includes some additional features not found in the main Firefox build.

**Basilisk:** This fork is based on the Firefox codebase but is focused on providing a more "privacy-respecting" browsing experience.

**LibreWolf:** This fork is based on the Firefox codebase but is focused on providing a more "privacy-respecting" browsing experience and remove telemetry and other features that may compromise user's privacy.